# Setting an ID for a selectize.js

Tags: selectize.js

Simple question: 
How do I set the ID for a selectize component? 
I tried to do so in this bracket:

```
{{ember-selectize
    id=name
    selection=selection
    content=attributes
    optionValuePath="content.key"
    optionLabelPath="content.value"
    ...
}}
```

But then the ID appears on the wrong level. Can anyone help?